# Building Python OCR using machine learning

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, ocr, text-extraction

There are a ton of questions dealing with OCR and Machine Learning, I am looking for guidance building my own from scratch.

I have an obscene number of photographs that contain text pertaining to the feature in the photo. The text is the latitude, longitude and id of the feature. I am looking for a way to extract this information into a text file to feed into my GIS.

I am sure Tesseract and Pytesseract would do exactly what I want, I however have a blocker in that I cannot load additional software onto the PC I am working on.

My PC is connected to a strictly controlled and secure network. I cannot install new software. I can however “pip install” any Python libraries needed, using a mobile hotspot. I have installed the Pytesseract library in Python. However if I have understood there is a dependency requiring a windows install file to be downloaded and installed before this works.

So I have decided to try (as a side project) create my own OCR model using Python and whatever libraries I need. The only issue is, there is a ton of information online and trying to find a focused and easy to follow process is not easy.

I am looking for resources detailing step by step what I need to do to create a training dataset, train a model and feed the images into the train model to get an output that makes sense.

I have been using OpenCv to process an image (crop, filter etc) to get bounding boxes of all the identifiable text in the test image. I am not sure where to go from there.

Are there any recommended  tutorials online / resources that might make sense to  a complete novice? I am using Python 3.5.

Comment: I am confused about your two conflicting comments: "I cannot load additional software" and "whatever libraries I need". Just as you installed any library (i.e., opencv), you can install pytesseract.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer there. I am on a very strict network and can not access sites easily from my pc. The libraries I can load using a mobile hotspot. Tesseract needs an install, which I cannot load. I cannot download the exe.